# Pass string containg "\" (backslash) to an ASPX page through Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, reporting-services

I have a situation where I have various string values in SSRS to an ASPX page (written in VB.Net).

I am currently facing two problems:

1. The backslash becomes lost on the transition when I try to same it back in the database. As a workaround is using the following:
   Request.QueryString("ParameterName").Insert(5, "\")
2. Since these can be any values; after the backslash a character could contain an Escape character e.i. "/" followed by a, b, f, n, r, t, u, v, x etc.
   In that case I still do not have a work around.

Here is an example of the Javascript I am passing:

```
javascript:void(window.open('http://sof/example.aspx?Param=" & Parameters!Param.Value 
   & "','_blank', 'scrollbars=yes', 'width=800,height=600'))","")
```

Comment: backslash and other special characters. Encode your url with this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Refer this - https://www.telerik.com/forums/slashes-dropped-from-string-parameter-of-javascript-method-when-using-responsescripts